# Injection of autowired dependencies failed inside a jar file

Tags: java, spring

I have put a jar file under lib folder of my war file. Inside the jar I have some classes with  @Autowired fileds. Inside the jar , in the applicationContext xml I have given

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.main.java.mypath" />
```

Code:

```
package com.main.java.mypath.client;

@Component
public class ServiceProvider {

   @Autowired
   private StoreField storeField;




package com.main.java.mypath.data;
public interface StoreField {
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.main.java.mypath.data.StoreField com.main.java.mypath.client.ServiceProvider.storeField; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.main.java.mypath.data.StoreField] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Do you *have* a candidate of type `StoreField` for injection?

Comment: What package do you use in your StoreField implementation?

Comment: `StoreField` is an interface as per the definition. Did you implement this interface on any class? Interfaces cannot be autowired. You need a class for autowiring.

Comment: Have you created your StoreField  implemented class in the same package?

Comment: No.. it seems the implementation class is in another jar file.. Missed out adding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to inject the dependency as long as you don't have the implementation for your `StoreField` interface. Make sure that it is implemented as a class and properly initialized in spring context via xml or annotation.

Comment: I am facing same problem but my Interface is JPARepository. and it is annotated by @Repository . But still spring is not able to create its bean. and I am getting Consider defining a bean of type '*.MissedIndexRepository' in your configuration.